# Get access token for more than one scope from GoogleAPI's in Android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have an application which requests youtube data api's. I need to have access token for some request like to get video's, playlist etc. For this I can simply use `GoogleAuthUtil` class to get Token by calling:

```
String access_token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Context, userEmail, "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");
```

Where third parameter is a `Scope` to get access token for particular request. Now I want to make a request which accepts 4 scope to give token back. And this method takes only one scope as an argument.

Is there a way to get access token with more than one scope in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken%28android.content.Context,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29),

"String representing the authentication scope. To specify multiple scopes, separate them with a space (for example, "oauth2:scope1 scope2 scope3")."

Also that such method is deprecated and you should use the  "getTokenWithNotification" version.

Comment: What a waste of time, I didn't read the complete documentation. Thanks for that